# How to search a string in an array of strings

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

Just an example so that it would clearer.

Lets say we have this assigned as strings in the array:

```
a(1) = Blue
a(2) = Red
a(3) = Orange
```

Then the string you want to find in the array is "Or"

I would then program a part of it like this:

```
word = "Or"
i = 1
j = 1
For a(i) to 3
if instr(a(i),word,1) <>0 Then
b(j) = a(i)
j = j + 1
end if
next i
```

This is the output intent. I would actually know which array - in this case array (3) contains the word "Or". This is the output I want.

I'm having a problem with using instr function as it doesn't recognize the string value in an array or even a string in a variable. I was wondering if there is another way to it without joining the strings in an array and then delimiting it later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about your provided code because if looks like syntax-error to me.

So I wrote a piece of code which serves your needs. Hope it can help.

```
Dim a(3) As String

a(0) = "Blue"
a(1) = "Red"
a(2) = "Orange"

Dim word As String

word = "Or"

Dim i As Integer

For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
    If InStr(a(i), word) Then
        Debug.Print "found at index " + CStr(i) + " : "; a(i)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for that, yes indeed it was syntax-error as I only placed a chunk of the code. I understand where I went wrong, cause I was trying to store a data in an excel sheet in an array without the quotation (" ") marks. No wonder why instr function did not work.